# Installation of TextBlob for Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, textblob

Team,

I installed python 3.4.1 version along with Anaconda. I am installed TextBlob, but it showing me error as,

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 import textBlob
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textBlob'

Help appreciated for this !!

Comment: does  `from textblob import TextBlob` work?

Comment: @pygri No.. Showing same error